# ffmpeg: add subtitles to mp4 with out creating a new file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitle

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -i infile.srt -c copy -c:s mov_text outfile.mp4
```

adds subtitles to `mp4` video but it creates a new file instead just adding few blocks of data to existing file.

Is there a way to modify existing video instead of creating a new one?

`subler` does it great with in a second, so should `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 5):

FFmpeg does not do in-place editing.